# An inequality involving positive real numbers which satisfy $a^2+b^2+c^2 = 3abc$

Tags: inequality

> Given that a, b, c are positive real numbers, show that
> $$ \frac{a}{b^2c^2}+\frac{b}{a^2c^2}+\frac{c}{b^2a^2} \ge \frac{9}{a+b+c} $$
> if $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 3abc$

My Attempt

> I wrote the inequality as $$ (a^3+b^3+c^3)*(a+b+c) \ge (a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 $$
> and after expanding and cancelling the terms we get
> $$ \sum_{cyclic}\{a^3(b+c)-a^2(b^2+c^2) \ = \ a^2b(a-b) + a^2c(a-c) \} $$
> now the sum is symmetric wrt a,b,c so if a $(b,a)$ term is there then there is a $(a,b)$ term so adding them separately gives the sum as
> $$ \sum_{cyclic}\{ab(a-b)^2\} $$
> so the inequality is true

But I was wondering whether there is an altenate way of proving this without using the right hand side of the inequality too much or any use of calculus is also good

---

Edit:
as @Isaac pointed out we can use Cauchy shwarz directly but is there any method which uses calculus

Comment: You can use Cauchy Schwarz immediately on the first inequality you write

Comment: oh i see @IsaacYIUMathStudio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$(a+b+c)\left(\frac{a}{b^2c^2}+\frac{b}{a^2c^2}+\frac{c}{b^2a^2}\right) \geqslant \left(\frac{a}{bc}+\frac{b}{ca}+\frac{c}{ab}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{abc}\right)^2  =9.$$
Therefore
$$\frac{a}{b^2c^2}+\frac{b}{a^2c^2}+\frac{c}{b^2a^2} \geqslant \frac{9}{a+b+c}.$$